# git: Can't comment on .gitignore file

Tags: git, gitignore

I've been trying to write some comments on my `.gitignore` file.
I started the comments with `#` but the sentences don't change into comments.
How can I solve this?

My `.gitignore` file looks like this:

```
# this is a comment 

db/* .sqlite3
```

Comment: could you please post your .gitignore file

Comment: #this is a comment
db/* .sqlite3

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> A line starting with # serves as a comment. Put a backslash ("\") in
>   front of the first hash for patterns that begin with a hash.

Whether your editor provides syntax highlight or not, `#` at the line start denotes a comment

Comment: I use sublime text, but it doesn't turn the sentences into comments.

Comment: Then it is an issue with syntax highlighting in sublime. Obviously, there is no configuration to colorize `.gitignore`-files. But that is not a problem, since git will handle them as comments anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be,  that you added sqlite before adding the entry to the. gitignore file?

You have to remove the file from the repo with

```
git rm --cached db/*.sqlite3
```

then commit the remove. 
It will be ignored afterwards.